# Updating SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server

I have a database AfricanRatings on which I used the query

```
INSERT INTO AfricanRatingsAVG
SELECT RecipeID,
       Count(*) AS cnt,
       AVG(Rating)
FROM   AfricanRatings
GROUP  BY RecipeID
ORDER  BY RecipeID
```

to get the average rating per recipe and the total count per recipeID.  The average and the count were placed into a table AfricanRatingsAVG via the query. On the initial query, AfricanRatingsAVG is updated but not with subsequent ratings.  I have tried all sorts of UPDATES to get the AfricanRatingAVG table to update every time a new rating is added to the AfricanRatings table, however, no update occurs.  Any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE
    AfricanRatingsAVG
SET
    AfricanRatingsAVG.RecipeID = AfricanRatings.RecipeID,
    AfricanRatingsAVG.cnt = AfricanRatings.Count(*),
    AfricanRatingsAVG.Expr1 = AfricanRatings.AVG(Rating)
FROM
    AfricanRatings
INNER JOIN
    AfricanRatingsAVG
ON
    AfricanRatingsAVG = AfricanRatings


UPDATE
    AfricanRatingsAVG
SET
    AfricanRatingsAVG.RecipeID = AfricanRatings.RecipeID,
    AfricanRatingsAVG.cnt = AfricanRatings.Count(*) AS cnt,
    AfricanRatingsAVG.Expr1 = AfricanRatings.AVG(Rating) AS Expr1
FROM
    AfricanRatings
INNER JOIN
    AfricanRatingsAVG
ON

Comment: Add the UPDATEs as edits to your original post, not as comments.

Answer (score 4):

Use an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) instead:

```
CREATE VIEW AfricanRatingsAVG
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT RecipeID,
       COUNT_BIG(*) AS cnt,
       AVG(Rating) as rating
FROM   dbo.AfricanRatings
GROUP  BY RecipeID;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdxAfricanRatingsAVG on AfricanRatingsAVG(RecipeID);
```

The engine will maintain the cnt and avg for you. [Use the NOEXPAND hint when querying the view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181151%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> When NOEXPAND is specified for a view, the query optimizer considers
>   using any indexes defined on the view.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. Got this error message:Unable to parse query text.
The query cannot be represented graphically
 in the Diagram and Criteria Pane.

Comment: This is not your query. This is the DDL you run to create the view, from your favorite management tool or from your deployment script. Your query designed will be  `SELECT ... FROM AfricanRatingsAVG WITH (NOEXPAND)`

Comment: Should be `SUM` instead of `AVG` in the view definition. (Well, not exactly, but `AVG` is disallowed; you get what I mean hopefully.)